# Vim mapping works in command mode but not when used in autocmd

Tags: vim, mapping, autocmd

I have this autocmd in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd Filetype markdown inoremap <buffer> <CR> <C-o>:call AutoUMDList()<CR>
```

When I open a markdown file, enter Insert mode and press `<CR>`, I get the following error:

```
E15: Invalid expression: ^O:call AutoUMDList()^M
E15: Invalid expression: ^O:call AutoUMDList()^M
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

But if I go in Insert mode and type `<C-o>:call AutoUMDList()<CR>` it works!

Also, if I type the following in Command mode it also works:

```
:inoremap <buffer> <CR> <C-o>:call AutoUMDList()<CR>
```

What is going on here please?! I don't understand why my autocmd won't work...

Comment: I can execute the command `autocmd Filetype markdown inoremap <buffer> <CR> <C-o>:call AutoUMDList()<CR>` without errors in Vim 7.4-32.

Comment: Me too; do you make modifications to `:set cpoptions`, or do you have `:set compatible`?!

Comment: My `cpoptions` are as follows: `cpoptions=aAceFsB` and I have `set nocompatible` as the first line of my `.vimrc`...